# Help solving the system below

Tags: diophantine-equations

I am trying to solve the system of diophantine equations below where $x,y$ are coprime

> \begin{eqnarray}
> xr^2+ys^2&=&uva\\
> xr+ys&= &uvb\\
> x+y&=&uc
> \end{eqnarray}

I solve 2 out of 3 then replace in the remaining one. However, things get messy at this point. I am unable to close the argument.Any hints?

Comment: I don't see any tries to solve that. It's understandable, 3 equations with 11 unknowns look sort of challenging, and there's also the nagging "what for?" you didn't try to address.

Comment: What is given and what are the variables?

Comment: I am trying to find $x,y$ such that the system remains consistent.

Comment: With specific integer values, it's simple. I am trying to find a general method.

Answer (score 2):

The system may not have any solution. For example, if $(r,s,u,v)=(1,1,5,6)$, then there is no solution for $x,y$. In general we can use that
$u$ divides $x+y$, $xr+ys$ and $xr^2+ys^2$. Similarly $v$ divides $xr+ys$ and $xr^2+ys^2$.

Comment: Why set $r=s=v=0$ to find all the possible solutions?

Comment: $x,y$ are the only variables.

Comment: @NumThcurious An absurd task. Express. $y=uc-x$ And you'll have the right answer. $$x=\frac{u(va-cs^2)}{r^2-s^2}=\frac{u(vb-cs)}{r-s}$$